Youtube Data V3 Python API add email to share private video
YouTube supports sharing a private video with certain google email addresses as shown in the screenshot
However, the Python API doesn't seem to have that option as to set a video as private, you just set
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "private"
  }

to mark it private but no option to share with emails.
Best I could do, is do it from the UI, copy the request as curl and then run a loop in a shell script to do it for multiple videos.
YouTube Help states that "Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-api, youtube-data-api, and youtube-v3-api tags." so I hope they see this one.
Expected the YouTube Data V3 API to fully cover all options I have as a user in the UI so that I can accomplish the same programmatically.

I have never seen Google engineers monitoring Stack Overflow questions. Your best luck is webscraping as you seem to know how to proceed.

You are correct this feature is not part of the API.  The api simply allows you access to the data behind Youtube it doesnt give you access to features within the UI part of YouTube
Sharing private videos is something you will need to do manually.
If you choose to do it an alternative way i suggest that you check the TOS to ensure this is not against it.  which i suspect it is

Thank you!
I wish this is added to the API in the future.
